# Why does lockCanvas take so long to lock?

Tags: android

I have a `SurfaceView` object with a `draw` method that gets called by 1 thread about 600 times from inside a `for` loop. No other thread calls `draw` during this time.

The draw method:

```
public void draw() {
    if(this.surface_created){
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        Log.d("GAME_SURFACE", "Time to lock:" + (System.nanoTime()-now));
        if (canvas == null)
        {
            System.out.println("[GameSurface] Cannot draw onto canvas as it's null");
        }
        else
        {

            canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, null, this.dest, null);
        }
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("[GameSurface] SURFACE NOT CREATED YET.");
    }

}
```

The problem happens when i use `holder.lockCanvas` , which takes around 14 million nanoseconds. So to draw all bitmaps it ends up taking 13 seconds to do so. Why is it taking so long? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Because lockCanvas invokes synchronization.  If something else is using it, it suspends the thread until its released and the thread is rescheduled.  A better question is why are you calling it multiple times per frame, rather than once as it was designed?

Comment: @GabeSechan I think i don't understand fully how `SurfaceView` works. My intention was to create the view, then draw to it as many times as i wanted like I would with drawing to a `Bitmap` using `Canvas`. Do I just need to lock the canvas once in `surfaceCreated` then call `draw` whenever I want, which has `unlockCanvasAndPost` at the end of the method?

Comment: When you call lockCanvas, you get a canvas to draw to.  When you call unlockCanvasAndPost, it will send that canvas to another thread, which will actually draw it to the screen.  So each one of those cycles is a frame.  You want to draw the complete view every frame, and then draw a new frame either when the view changes or on a timer.  So if you wanted to draw 12 bitmaps to the view, you would draw 12 bitmaps between calling lock and unlock.  If you wanted to draw one bitmap now and one bitmap in 16ms (say for animation), then you'd lock and unlock one for each of those separate drawings.

Comment: @GabeSechan Makes so much more sense now. Thanks!